# What is the difference between ffmpeg command with -codec and without -codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to calculate video frozen time, I created `mp4` format file with 23seconds frozen.
I am converting `mp4` file into `segment(.ts)` file using following command

```
ffmpeg -i Palivala.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 palivaalaa.ts
```

When i directly use video file (Palivala.mp4) or segment file(palivaalaa.ts) which generated from above command, I am getting the result as expected. i.e getting video frozen time as 23seconds.

But when I use following command

```
ffmpeg -i Palivala.mp4  -map 0 palivaalaa.ts
```

I am able to see 1second frozen frames then after that 1 frame without frozen immediately next frame frozen and frozen continued for 6seconds again 1 non-frozen frame...................

1) What is the difference between above 2 commands?

2) both commands chooses `libx264`?

Comment: 1) `-codec` specify how to deal with output codec. And `ffmpeg` has some default behavior when it is not given. 2) For which encoder will be chosen, checkout stdout/stderr output by `ffmpeg`.

Comment: how to check stdout/stderr output by ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

“Both commands choose libx264”.  No, the first command doesn’t choose anything because nothing is being encoded. The frames are “copied”from source to destination. In the second example, every frames is decoded, then reencoded before being written to the file.

Comment: How do I edit my first command(`ffmpeg -i Palivala.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 palivaalaa.ts`) to choose libx264